# Is it possible to have a mysql query with a different where clause for each select?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a query that counts the number of sales this week. It looks like this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(SOLD), COUNT(*) FROM SALES_DATA 
WHERE SOLD BETWEEN '2012/10/14 00:00:00' AND '2012/10/21 00:00:00' AND STORE_ID = 1010         GROUP BY DAYNAME(SOLD) ORDER BY DAY(SOLD);
```

And the output looks like this:

```
DAYNAME(SOLD)   COUNT(*)
Sunday          400
Monday          375
Etc.            Etc.
```

I would like to have a third column of sales from the week before for comparison. But to do this I would need to have a separate where clause with a different date range. So my question is how would I accomplish this? I am pretty new to mysql and haven't found anything like this. Would a join work? I'm not quite sure how those work. My desired output would be like this:

```
DAYNAME(SOLD)   COUNT(*)   COUNT(*)
Sunday          400        550
Monday          375        250
Etc.            Etc.       Etc.
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a structure like this:

```
select stuff1.common_col, stuff1.col1, stuff2.col2
from
(select common_col, col1 from somewhere where ... ) as stuff1
(select common_col, col1 from somewhere where ... ) as stuff2
where stuff1.common_col = stuff2.common_col
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no luck. Maybe I'm not doing it right. Here's what I tried: 'select lastweek.DAYNAME(SOLD), lastweek.COUNT(*), prevweek.COUNT(*)
from
(select DAYNAME(SOLD), COUNT(*) from SALES_DATA where SOLD BETWEEN '2012/10/14 00:00:00' AND '2012/10/21 00:00:00' AND STORE_ID = 1010 ) as lastweek
(select DAYNAME(SOLD), COUNT(*) from SALES_DATA where SOLD BETWEEN '2012/10/07 00:00:00' AND '2012/10/14 00:00:00' AND STORE_ID = 1010 ) as prevweek
where lastweek.DAYNAME(SOLD) = prevweek.DAYNAME(SOLD) GROUP BY DAYNAME(SOLD) ORDER BY DAY(SOLD);' Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the group by clause looks like it should go inside each subquery